# Java using URLConnection to curl with --verbose switch

Tags: java, curl, urlconnection, verbose

I am trying to make a curl request using java.net.URLConnection.
However, I need to parse the output of the command when executed with the  --verbose switch.

The following code executes the curl request as intended, I'm just looking for a way to get the verbose output of the command.

```
        String stringUrl = this.contUrl + "/auth?action=login";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        System.out.println(stringUrl);
        System.out.println("Authorization: " + this.header);

        uc.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", this.header);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        String result = "";
        String line;    
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? What is --verbose switch?

Comment: `curl` is a command-line tool. You're not running `curl`, you're running Java code, so there is no such thing as a "curl request". Assuming the value of `this.contUrl` starts with `http:`, you're making an "HTTP request". If you want your Java code to write output similar to what [`--verbose`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) does for `curl`, it's up to you to write the code to print request and response headers, accessible by calling methods on [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#method.summary).

Comment: @TuyenNguyen See `curl` manpage: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-v

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I was well aware that I was running Java code and not the command-line tool curl.


 "it's up to you to write to code to print request and response headers" was exactly the point in the right direction I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to read the output from command line, hope this help:

```
private String readCommandOutput(String pattern) throws IOException {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    String charset = "utf-8";
    int result = bis.read();
    String output = "";
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while (result != -1) {
        buf.write((byte) result);
        output = buf.toString(charset);
        if (!output.equals(lineSeparator)) {
            String output_arr[] = output.split(lineSeparator);
            String lastLine = output_arr[output_arr.length - 1];

            // check if this is the end of stream and the pattern is match
            if (lastLine.endsWith(pattern) && bis.available() == 0) {
                return output;
            } 
        }           
        result = bis.read();
    }
    return buf.toString(charset);
}
```

This code I used a `pattern` is a String to determine when will the command finish it job to stop reading from the stream. I don't know what is the output of your program, you can refer to my code to modify suitable to yours.